# Updated value in Firebase is not being updated right away on label

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made simple Firebase project where I can update some values in Firebase tree specifically `reputation` child. But the problem is that it is updated in Firebase right away, but not on on label in application. What is the of cause this?

This is the code how I update the value:

```
self.databaseRef.child("users").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).child("reputation").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            //check to see if the node exists, if not give value of 0.
            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        })
```

And I get the value like this:

```
let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

            if let reputation = snapshot["reputation"] {
                self.reputationLabel.text = "\(reputation)"
            } else {
                print("reputation is nil")
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(loggedInUser!.uid)/reputation").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        if let data = currentData.value as? Int{

            currentData.value = data + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }else{

            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        }

        }, andCompletionBlock: {(err,completion,updatedData) in

            if completion{

                print(updatedData!.value)
                self.reputationLabel.text = "\((updatedData!.value)!)"
            }else{

                print("Couldnt update")

            }
    })

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me error: "runTransactionBlock: usage detected while persistence is enabled. Please be aware that transactions *will not* be persisted across app restarts. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-handling-transactions-offline for more details.
Optional(<null>)" 

But it updated it right away and put null inside label :) Does it mean I have to take the persistance away from appdelegate and can't cahce values?

I tried removing the line from delegate but now it just gives null. not nil.

Comment: If your persistence is enabled then you will have to update the label in the first block where you update the value. I am guessing this wont be an issue when your user is online. But for offline user you have to do this.

Comment: But even if I removed the persistence I get null.

Comment: Nope. And I do not see the reason why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124933/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-dravidian).

Comment: Yes it is working but with some delay. But for some reason it adds 2 instead of 1. Why is that?

Comment: If you are using the exact syntax that i have answered checking with `if let data = currentData.value as? Int{` block, It really shouldn't. runTransactionBlock keep's on firing until it has found the value... So that might be the issue.